# How to get the local maximum in row ranges in a 1D dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've a dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
    data=[[0, 2, 42, 50, 46, 6, 0, 0, 1, 41, 49, 45, 5, 0]]
)
```

like this

```
    1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3
0   0   2   42  50  46  6   0   0   1   41  49  45  5   0
```

and I'd like to get

```
    1.0   1.1   1.2   1.3  1.4   1.5   1.6   1.7   1.8   1.9   2.0   2.1   2.2   2.3
0   False False False True False False False False False False True  False False False
```

(note: I'm using a dataframe cause I manage other data for each column in addition.). How can I get a dataframe like this e.g. using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) with [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so called local max, we can do `argrelextrema`

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
idx=argrelextrema(df.loc[0].values,np.greater)
df.columns[idx[0]]
Out[227]: Float64Index([1.3, 2.0], dtype='float64')
```

To match the output

```
df[:]=df.columns.isin(df.columns[idx[0]])
df
Out[234]: 
     1.0    1.1    1.2   1.3    1.4  ...    1.9   2.0    2.1    2.2    2.3
0  False  False  False  True  False  ...  False  True  False  False  False
[1 rows x 14 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the values to int and find the max by group:

```
result = df.groupby(df.columns.astype(int), axis=1).idxmax()
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     1    2
0  1.3  2.0
```

If you want to match exactly your output you could do:

```
groups = df.groupby(df.columns.astype(int), axis=1).idxmax()

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=groups.values.flatten(), data=groups.values.astype(bool))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
    1.3   2.0
0  True  True
```

**UPDATE**

Given the new requirements you could do:

```
groups = df.groupby(df.columns.astype(int), axis=1).idxmax()
result = pd.DataFrame(data=[df.columns.isin(groups.values.flatten())], columns=df.columns.values)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     1.0    1.1    1.2   1.3    1.4  ...    1.9   2.0    2.1    2.2    2.3
0  False  False  False  True  False  ...  False  True  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x=df.sort_values(by=0, axis=1, ascending=False).columns

df[x[:2]]=True
df[x[2:]]=False
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
1.0    1.1    1.2   1.3  ...   2.0    2.1    2.2    2.30  
False  False  False  True  ...  True  False  False  False
[1 rows x 14 columns]

[Program finished]
```